# How to send data into a channel for testing purposes in Golang?

Tags: testing, go, switch-statement, channel

I'm trying to write unit tests for functions for a project in Go and I'm coming up against a problem I've never encountered before. The function is used in a loop that monitors Slack (the messaging platform) live for certain event structures (defined by a library I'm using) and responds according depending on the event returned (using a switch). Here's (most of) the code:

```
func botLoop(s *SlackBot) {
    select {
    case rtmEvent := <-s.Rtm.IncomingEvents:
        switch ev := rtmEvent.Data.(type) {
        case *slack.MessageEvent:

            o, err := s.HandleCommand(ev)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
                s.Say(ev.Channel, "%s\n", err)
                break
            }
            s.Say(ev.Channel, o)

         case *slack.LatencyReport:
             fmt.Printf("Current latency: %v\n", ev.Value)

         default:
             // fmt.Printf("Unexpected: %v\n", msg.Data)
    }
}
```

How can I pass "rtmEvents" into the s.Rtm.IncomingEvent channel to trigger my code for testing purposes? Is there any way to reliably do this?

[Here's the documentation for the API library I'm using](https://godoc.org/github.com/nlopes/slack#RTM), if that makes things any easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Slackbot is the your custom type. Since RTM is an exported type, for testing you could create a new RTM struct with a new chan. Then using a go routine start sending  messages to that channel. And run your function in other go routine which will listen for messages.

Also I suggest replying select with range since you are listening on only one chan